# Adding a New Column to a Postgres Partition Master Table

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a table:

```
dw_readings(date_key, time_key, account_key, reading_value, consumption, processed_date)
```

which has been partitioned on `date_key` by year. I now have need to add a `reading_id` column to the master table to support new functionality, however using the `alter table` statement doesn't seem to work correctly. After applying the `alter` to add the new `reading_id` column any `insert into dw_readings` results in `reading_id` being set to `null` despite the value being set in the `insert` statement; this can be reproduced through Java JDBC and through pgAdmin. However `update` statements setting the `reading_id` work correctly allowing me to set the column value.

The table is being altered using the following statement

```
ALTER dw_readings ADD COLUMN reading_id INTEGER;
```

What I need to know is how to properly add a new column to a partitioned table so that inserts work properly.

Comment: Show us the `ALTER` and INSERT statements you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to track down the issue in the code. The problem had to do with the rule sets created for the partitions.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE RULE dw_readings_insert_y2009 AS
       ON INSERT TO dw_readings
       WHERE new.date_key >= 20090101 AND new.date_key < 20100101
       DO INSTEAD 
    INSERT INTO dw_readings_y2009 (date_key, time_key, account_key, reading_value, consumption, processed_date) 
      VALUES (new.date_key, new.time_key, new.account_key, new.reading_value, new.consumption, new.processed_date);
```

This rule did not include the new column and so would always insert null for the reading_id. The solution was to add reading_id to the INSERT statement of the DO INSTEAD.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it. Note that when you create a new column all the pre existing rows will have a null value in that column:

```
create table dw_readings(date_key date);
create table dw_readings_2012(
    check (extract(year from date_key) = 2012)
)   inherits(dw_readings);
;
insert into dw_readings_2012 (date_key) values ('2012-01-01'::date);
alter table dw_readings add column reading_id integer;
insert into dw_readings_2012 (date_key, reading_id) values ('2012-01-02'::date, 2);
select *
from dw_readings
;
  date_key  | reading_id 
------------+------------
 2012-01-01 |           
 2012-01-02 |          2
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @xstrike mentioned, it should be enough to reload the rules. 
E.g if you have rune on insert you have to replace it on each partition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE table_partition_201608_rule
AS ON INSERT TO table_master WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-08-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-08-31 23:59:59.999'
DO INSTEAD (
  INSERT INTO table_partition_201608 VALUES (NEW.*)
);
```

Comment: Spot the Dungeons and Dragons reference :D